# How to use for loop in the CQL statement

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a table with columns that have one to many relationship. For example I have table called `Lines` that has columns `market`, `maker`. A market has many makers.

How can I retrieve the 500 most recent records for each market and maker type from Cassandra?

Update:

I want to retrieve 500 rows for each pair of `market` and `maker`. Since a `market` can have multiple `makers` there will be many combinations of `market` and `maker` because of the one to many relationship.

I don't have access to the schema at the moment. I just know the fields in the table `Lines`. I just want to know if its possible to have some sort of loop - most efficient way to retrieve for each `market` and `maker`, the most 500 recent records. I'm ok with CQL or Java solution.

Comment: do u want 500 rows for each pair of `market, maker`? Or for each market, u need 500 maker rows?

Comment: what is the schema for your table?

Comment: @AlexOtt  I've updated the question